# How to debug Riak-cs not finding admin credentials?

Tags: riak, riak-cs

I am setting up a new cluster. I followed all the setup instructions (I
think). I created admin user as doc says, then updated riak-cs.conf and
stanchion.conf with generated keys. I get the following when starting:

> 2016-05-05 01:15:01.167 [error]
>   <0.149.0>@riak_cs_app:fetch_and_cache_admin_creds:96 Couldn't get admin
>   user (LMTLWU8QZ_UZZJ4Y541) record: {error,notfound}
>   2016-05-05 01:15:01.199 [error] <0.149.0>@riak_cs_app:sanity_check:129
>   Admin credentials are not properly set: notfound.

If I revert back to default ('admin.key = admin-key'), then it starts OK.
If I try to create the user again, it says the email already exists. So
it's there.

I looked at the logs and didn't find anything that seems relevant other
these entries I just posted.

Comment: If the email is already attached to a user, can you directly query Riak using the email_bin index against the moss.users bucket to see if it returns the same key?

Comment: Thank you! using your comment I could verify it was actually there. still not sure why it won't correctly find it, tough.

Comment: @joe I deleted the data dir, restart and created the account. On the first restart after setting admin.key I got some errors on stanchion. but restarting again it worked. It does not inspire much confidence, will test more.

Comment: I set up a new CS cluster and didn't have any issue setting this.  Is it possible that your editor is using a charset other than ASCII when modifying the config?

Comment: @joe I don't think so, there was nothing special about the id in question. hard to tell what was wrong. Anyway, thanks for the help and it is working now